# Python Class passing value to "self"

Tags: python, scipy, self

I'm programming an optimizer that has to run through several possible variations. The team wants to implement multithreading to get through those variants faster. This means I've had to put all my functions inside a thread-class. My problem is with my call of the wrapper function

```
class variant_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, variant, frequencies, fit_vals):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.elementCount = variant
        self.frequencies = frequencies
        self.fit_vals = fit_vals
    
    def run(self):
        print("Running Variant:", self.elementCount) # display thread currently running
        fitFunction = self.Wrapper_Function(self.elementCount)
    
        self.popt, pcov, self.infoRes = curve_fit_my(fitFunction, self.frequencies, self.fit_vals)

    def Optimize_Wrapper(self, frequencies, *params): # wrapper which returns values in manner which optimizer can work with
        cut = int(len(frequencies)/2) <---- ERROR OCCURS HERE
        freq = frequencies[:cut]
        vals = (stuff happens here)
        return (stuff in proper form for optimizer)
```

I've cut out as much as I could to simplify the example, and I hope you can understand what's going on. Essentially, after the thread is created it calls the optimizer. The optimizer sends the list of frequencies and the parameters it wants to change to the Optimize_Wrapper function.

The problem is that Optimize-Wrapper takes the frequencies-list and saves them to "self". This means that the "frequencies" variable becomes a single float value, as opposed to the list of floats it should be. Of course this throws an errorswhen I try to take len(frequencies). Keep in mind I also need to use self later in the function, so I can't just create a static method.

I've never had the problem that a class method saved any values to "self". I know it has to be declared explicitly in Python, but anything I've ever passed to the class method always skips "self" and saves to my declared variables. What's going on here?

Comment: You should check your indentation. Currently your `run` and `Optimize_Wrapper` methods are not inside you class. Correct indentation is part of posting a [mre].

Comment: Apologies, I had trouble figuring out how to post code here. I promise you that's not the problem in my IDE. I have fixed the indentation.

Comment: Your `__init__` takes a variable called `variant` and saves it as `self.elementCount`. When you call `Optimize_Wrapper` its now a parameter called `frequencies`. If frequencies isn't correct then the original value passed in to initialize the thread isn't correct.

Comment: @tdelaney Apologies again, that's because of my poor attempt to minimize superfluous information in my example. I've readded the variables which will define the frequency-list used in optimizer. The issue has nothing to do with variant.

Comment: As an aside, unless the variant processing includes making blocking operating system calls or calls to a C extension that releases the python GIL, multithreading won't speed things up. Python only lets a single python thread run at a time.

Comment: @tdelaney Really? That's actually very helpful information, and will save me a lot of time if I don't go down this route. How can I speed up the process then? Using Multiprocess instead of Multithread?

Comment: Additional note: Multi-threading in python will still use one CPU at a time because of the python GIL. So multi threading is only effective if you are parallelizing time consuming tasks (e.g. reading large files). It will only impose an overhead if you are parallelizing computationally intensive tasks

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ How would you suggest running multiple optimization processes at the same time?

Comment: "This means that the "frequencies" variable becomes a single float value, as opposed to the list of floats it should be. " why does it mean that? you can assign lists to a variable. You're *not* passing in a list of frequencies to `Optimize_Wrapper` otherwise your code would be okay. Where are you calling `Optimize_Wrapper` and what are you calling it with? Or is init supposed to call `Optimize_Wrapper` instead of `Wrapper_Function`?

Comment: @alkasm The Optimize_Wrapper function gets called from curve_fit_my, which is a variation of the scipy.optimize.curve_fit function. This function *does* pass the frequencies to the Optimize_Wrapper function. As I stated in the post above, the problem is that the list gets saved to the "self" variable, which I thought was protected. When I add "print(self)" as the function's first line, the program prints the list of frequencies.

Comment: @MasterAtBeingHelpless You can use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module but make sure not to give very short time tasks to a process since there will be an added overhead from the new process creation. Or there are several other modules which can perform better than multiprocessing in some cases such as [ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @MasterAtBeingHelpless Maybe you should add a minimal reproducible example of the code and the expected result. Just show the list passing and the error happening. Your question is not very clear

Comment: Here's the general problem: with methods on a class, there is the function definition itself (which includes needing to pass the self object explicitly) and a _bound method_ which already has self passed in. `self.method` is a bound method, while `class.method` is not bound. Something that you're doing is not passing a bound method where someone else invokes it. The solution is to pass a bound method or to pass an instance to whatever calls your function to use that as the first argument. Alternatively, if you're not using `self` in the function, just turn it into a normal function.

Comment: How best to do this depends on how the variants are calculated. Ideally, everything can be done independently and then you can write a separate .py file to do each one, writing the result to stdout. Now, a thread pool can be used run each variant via `subprocess.run` and aggregate the results coming back from stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass instance variables to methods. They are already accessible through `self`. And be careful about which variable is which. The first parameter to `Wrapper_function` is called "frequency", but you call it as `self.Wrapper_Function(self.elementCount)` - so you have a `self.frequency` and a `frequency` ... and they are different things. Very confusing!

```
class variant_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, variant, frequencies, fit_vals):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.elementCount = variant
        self.frequencies = frequencies
        self.fit_vals = fit_vals
    
    def run(self):
        print("Running Variant:", self.elementCount) # display thread currently running
        fitFunction = self.Wrapper_Function()
        self.popt, pcov, self.infoRes = curve_fit_my(fitFunction, self.frequencies, self.fit_vals)

    def Optimize_Wrapper(self): # wrapper which returns values in manner which optimizer can work with
        cut = int(len(self.frequencies)/2) <---- ERROR OCCURS HERE
        freq = self.frequencies[:cut]
        vals = (stuff happens here)
        return (stuff in proper form for optimizer)
```

You don't have to subclass `Thread` to run a thread. Its frequently easier to define a function and have `Thread` call that function. In your case, you may be able to put the variant processing in a function and use a thread pool to run them. This would save all the tedious handling of the thread object itself.

```
def run_variant(name, variant, frequencies, fit_vals):
    cut = int(len(self.frequencies)/2) <---- ERROR OCCURS HERE
    freq = self.frequencies[:cut]
    vals = (stuff happens here)
    proper_form = (stuff in proper form for optimizer)
    return curve_fit_my(fitFunction, self.frequencies, self.fit_vals)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    variants = (make the variants)
    name = "name"
    frequencies = (make the frequencies)
    fit_vals = (make the fit_vals)
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        for popt, pcov, infoRes in pool.starmap(run_variant,
                ((name, variant, frequencies, fit_vals) for variant in variants)):
            # do the other work here
```

Comment: While I would very much prefer your method, the reason I'm passing those variables to the function is because I'm actually passing them to an outside function, which is then calling back to the class function. Scipy.Optimize.curve_fit looks at the variables you give it to determine the number of optimizable parameters. This is why I have the function Optimize_Wrapper defined this way, the optimizer reads the number of passed variables, including the frequency list, from the function declaration. If it weren't for that, this whole thing would be trivial.